# Javascript initialize events from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i have plugin construction like this:

```js
(function($){
    
        var defaults = {
            param1:null,
            param2:null
        };
    
        var methods = {
            init:function(params) {
    
                var options = $.extend({}, defaults, params);
    
                $(this).append('<button class="addbtn">Add elements</button>');
    
                $(document).on('click','.addbtn',function(){
                     $('body').append(button.html+input.html);
                });
    
    
            }
        };
    
        var button = {
            html: '<button class="btn">Button</button>'
        };
    
        var input = {
            html: '<input type="text" class="input" value="" />'
        };
    
        var actions ={
            clicked:function(){
                alert('clicked');
            },
            hover:function(){
                alert('hover');
            }
        };
    
        $.fn.JPlugin = function(method){
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method"' +  method + '" is not found jQuery.mySimplePlugin' );
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
    $('body').JPlugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

By clicking on add button you will add input from `input.html` and button from `button.html`. How can i initialize click event for input element and button objects from `actions.clicked` and hover event from `actions.hover`

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define events when append button and input.Try following code i hope this helpful.

```js
(function($){
    
        var defaults = {
            param1:null,
            param2:null
        };
    
        var methods = {
            init:function(params) {
    
                var options = $.extend({}, defaults, params);
    
                $(this).append('<button class="addbtn">Add elements</button>');
    
                $(document).on('click','.addbtn',function(){
                     $('body').append(button.html+input.html)
                      .find(".foo")
                      .click(function(){actions.clicked($(this))})
                      .hover(function(){actions.hover($(this))})
                });
    
               
            }
        };
    
        var button = {
            html: '<button class="btn foo">Button</button>'
        };
    
        var input = {
            html: '<input type="text" class="input foo" value="" />'
        };
    
        var actions ={
            clicked:function($this){
                console.log($this);
            },
            hover:function($this){
                console.log($this);
            }
        };
    
        $.fn.JPlugin = function(method){
            if ( methods[method] ) {
                return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
            } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
            } else {
                $.error( 'Method"' +  method + '" is not found jQuery.mySimplePlugin' );
            }
        };
    })(jQuery);
    $('body').JPlugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!
One question: How can i manupulate with current object in actions.clicked function? I mean to send current object to actions.clicked